# How to add views to a controller in a ruby on rails application manually(not through controller wizard)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, rubymine

I am using Ruby mine for building a ruby on rails application. Everything is working fine. I create new project and then press Ctrl+Alt+G. From the generator option I choose controller. Then I get a window in which i have to name controller and actions. When I select different actions, corresponding functions are created in the controller named after my actions. If i press an icon to the left of that functions name I get a view file opened for that particular function having extension.html.erb.This is fine. But what if i forget to add one or more action in the controller dialog box. Then supposedly I have to add a function whose name is the view I want. i.e.

```
def functionname

end
```

Now when i click on the left of this functionname. I get an option to create a file of extension .html.erb. All of this is working fine. But when I build this application and try to access this newly created view I get the following error`

```
    Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/say_hello/sona"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

How can i add views to a controller except using that controller wizard??Can't I add view afterwards??
`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know the wizard but to access an URL in your application you need:

## Route

Defined in `config/routes.rb`, in your case:

```
get 'say_hello/sona', to: 'your_controller#your_action'
```

## Controller

Defined in `app/controllers/your_controller.rb`

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def your_action
  end
end
```

## Template or view

Defined in `app/views/your_controller/your_action.html.erb`, you could leave this file empty, but it has to be created.

Comment: you gave me a hint........what i had to do was for every view that i create manually I had to add following line to routes.rb....
get"Contollername/Viewname". This should have been added automatically to routes.rb when i create a new view or file of extension .html.erb.